# tinymce - how to disable smart paste

Tags: tinymce

When I paste something in tinymce editor and save it to db it automatically saves all styles related to that copy. I would like only to keep html tags but not css styles. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

You may use the tinymce init configuration parameter paste_remove_styles

```
paste_remove_styles: true,
```

there are even far more settings concerning paste - those you can find [here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste).

Answer (score 2):

just add this line

> paste_remove_styles: true

Comment: -1 your post adds nothing to answers already available. where should he add this line? do you even know what tinymce is about?